# Php - PDO Database

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Below is my function to check radio button questions to the answer with the answer stored in the database.

```
function chkQuestions($info)
{   
    $query = $this->handle->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbltest");
    $query->execute();
    $rows = $query->fetchAll();

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {

        $answerID = array($info['answer'.$row['testID']]);


            if ($row['answer'] == $answerID ) 
                {
                      $score = 0;
                      $result = $score +1;
                      return $result;
                } else {
                      $result = "incorrect";
                     return $result;
                }
            //return $answerID;

    }//rows

}//chkQuestions
```

My problem is that this code I did works well for a single question but I not sure how to make it work for multiple questions

info about my code.

&info is an array that stores all the $_POST data.

$row['answer'];  - this is referring to my answer row in the database.

The Post data is submitted into the function and looks like this

```
<input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>" id="answer<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>" value="<?php echo $question['option3']?>" />
```

$questions is an array with database data which assign each question withthe ID of a database row, which i use to submit to the chkquestion function to match the id of the row to that question.

im stuck on how to make this work for multiple questions.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have form field names like `answer[1]`, `answer[2]` and when submitted to PHP, they will be parsed as an array. I hope you can rework your code with this knowledge. Right now they are a mess to me.

```
name="answer[<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>]"
```

Comment: hello Turtletread,  can u explain to me what you are doing here ?

Comment: sorry turtle it wasnt showing lol,  yes that seems to be getting me somewhere tho now im getting this               error. Notice: Undefined index: answer1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProgramLearnWeb\model\html.model.php on line 46

Comment: i assume from this it now not storeing the value in this input in the post type

Comment: The method here is simple. You get an array from the form and iterate through them to do the processing. You need to debug the code on your own. I suggest that you understand what values are being passed to and from. use var_dump to help you.