# PDO PHP Array issue

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

```
function chkQuestions($info)
    {
        $query = $this->handle->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbltest");
        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchAll();
        $getPost = $query->rowCount();  

        foreach($rows as $row) {
            for($i = 1; $i <= $getPost; $i++) {
                $answerID[$i] = array($info['answer'.$i]);
                $lo = array($answerID);
            }

            foreach($answerID as $question) {
                if(array_key_exists($row['answer'],$question)) {
                    $test = "found";
                    return $test;
                } else {
                    return $question;
                }
            }                           
        }   
    }//chkQuestions
```

Above is my function, all works,  but when I compare the row in my database called answer with the array it doesn't work?

I tried hard coding in the value and it works correctly but not with the array.

I checked to see the values of array and the value is indeed there.

In logic `$answerID[$i] = array($info['answer'.$i]);` = `option1` and if the array value `option1` = the database row answer which is set to `option1` than return found, but it tells me it cannot find it.

```
array(1)
    {
        [0]=> string(7) "option1"
    }
```

Above is the `dum_var` of the array `$question`. Any help?

```
foreach($questions as $question)
            {
            ?>
            <h3><?php echo $question['question'] ?></h3>

            <div class = "col-xs-12">

            <input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>" id="answer<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>" value="<?php echo $question['option1']?>" />

            <label for="question-1-answers-A">A)<?php echo $question['option1'] ?> </label>

            </div>

            <div class = "col-xs-12">

            <input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>" id="answer<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>" value="<?php echo $question['option2']?>" />

            <label for="question-1-answers-B">B)<?php echo $question['option2'] ?></label>

            </div>

            <div class = "col-xs-12">

            <input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>" id="answer<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>" value="<?php echo $question['option3']?>" />

            <label for="question-1-answers-C">C)<?php echo $question['option3'] ?></label>

            </div>

            <div class = "col-xs-12">

            <input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>" id="answer<?php echo $question['testID'] ?>" value="<?php echo $question['option4']?>" />

            <label for="question-1-answers-D">D)<?php echo $question['option4'] ?></label>
            <br>
            <br>


            </div>


            <?php
            }
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='subaction' id='subaction' value='chkQuestion'> <button class='btn btn-primary' name='submit' type='submit'>Submit</button> </form>";

        }
        else
            echo "No Quiz Found </form>";










    ?>   
   </div>
```

Comment: I will help you with this.  There are a few things that I think need correcting.  Let's start by clarifying the resultset.  You are selecting with `*`.  Are you only using values from the `answer` column of the table?  If so, please literally name it in your query.  I have follow up questions, but I'll wait until you respond on this first point before I fire more questions at you.

Comment: Actually, you should probably fix up your form field naming issue from your earlier question before moving onto all of the fixes needed with this question.  Please update this question to reflex the changes made there.

Comment: Hello, i have fixed the statement to look for answer in the database. and all prevoius questions was sorted, all form info does reach this function

Comment: So we are using `"SELECT answer FROM tbltest"` as a query?  What is `handle->`, is it just the connection?  The next question is, why use `fetchAll()`?  This will return two duplicate elements with keys: `0` and `answer` for each row.  Would `fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` be better?  Your nested looping is very concerning; this whole section requires some scrutiny.

Comment: You don't appear to be using any ORDER BY clause on your query.  Are you absolutely certain that your resultset will come in the exact order that your `$info['answer']` array will be ordered?

Comment: `$lo = array($answerID);` seems useless.  Why do you declare it?  Same with `for($i = 1; $i <= $getPost; $i++) {`  why are you looping here?

Comment: After rereading this question and your other question, it seems you should be SELECTing `testID` and `answer` to ensure everything is sync'ed up nicely.

Comment: Hello, yes I'm using the select answer from tbltest,   I tested the created array and it did have the value option1 which I was looking for and no other values.    $lo = array($answerID); is a test variable i should of commented it out.  the reason for looping here is ill have more than one question which is looped to output from database. so to put each question with unqiue id i set the name element nd id to answer1, the number refers to the row of the database for example answer is row 1, answer2 is row 2

Comment: that is correct i am selecting testID and answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a lot of confidence in my answer because your coding method does a good job of confusing me.  However, I feel like I need to get something on the page so we have some sort of solid base to work from:

```
function chkQuestions($info){
    $check=array(); // this will hold the results to return
    $stmt=$this->handle->prepare("SELECT `testID`,`answer` FROM tbltest");
    $stmt->execute(); 
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if($info['answer'][$row['testID']]==$row['answer']){
            $check[$row['testID']]="correct";
        }else{
            $check[$row['testID']]="incorrect";
        }
    }
    return $check;  // handle this however you like on your main page
}
```

Comment: @SeafightBlackPearl21 See if you can get this clean code block to work for you.  If not, please tell me what isn't working as expected or what you don't understand.

Comment: hey, ill give it a go now =-)

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: answer in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProgramLearnWeb\model\html.model.php on line 43
array(1) { [1]=> string(9) "incorrect" }    is the response im looking now to see whats sup

Comment: It would help me if I could see some sample data for `$info` and `$row`.  (in your question via an edit would be best)

Comment: ok it worked i changed it to if($info['answer'.$row['testID']]==$row['answer']){

Comment: @SeafightBlackPearl21 if you are using: `$info['answer'.$row['testID']]` then you didn't take the good advice given to you @ your other related question ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/43439880/2943403 ).

Comment: @SeafightBlackPearl21 How are you identifying your questions? I mean how do you identify them within $info and your database.  This is why I could use some sample data.

Comment: Im using a MVC framework,  the $info contains all the data from $_POST and submitted by a post to the model,,  ill show the questions now

Comment: i tried that later method nd i get this   
Notice: Undefined index: answer1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProgramLearnWeb\model\html.model.php on line 43

Notice: Undefined index: answer2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProgramLearnWeb\model\html.model.php on line 43

Comment: @SeafightBlackPearl21   Please do some sort of `print_r`/`var_export` on `$info` and `$row` within your function, then I should be able to help you effectively.

Comment: thank you for ur support mick, i have gotten it to work. 5 star help

Comment: @SeafightBlackPearl21 If my answer was helpful you may upvote it.  Also, if there is a way to work toward an accepted answer, this would help to identify your question as resolved and help future readers to move quickly to the best answer.  Am I able to edit my answer to earn the green tick? or are you able to post an answer and award it a green tick?

Comment: sure =-) ill do that now